# Identifying processes that open MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, connections, debugging

I need to identify which application process issues a large number of MySQL connections on a Linux system.

The `show processlist` sql command or tools like innotop do not really help, as they only show db user and host, and i doubt that i catch all statements that way.

I was thinking to use something on the network level, like tcpdump or netstat. Any suggestions?

Comment: try using something like [tcpaccept](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/master/tools/tcpaccept.bt) in bcc-tools.

Answer (score 0):

It seems

```
ss -p '( dport = :mysql )'
```

does the trick, listing the process ids of the processes on the local machine that connect to the mysql driver's port.